# Python: Dividing values of nested list with values with values of dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list:

```
mylist = [['A',4,2,5], ['C',3,9,5], ['D',2,5,6]]
```

And a dictionary:

```
mydict = {'A' : 2, 'B' : 6, 'C' : 3}
```

I want to divide the nested list with the value of mydict if the first value of the nested list is matched with the key of mydict.

mylist2 should look like this:

```
mylist2 = [['A',2,1,2.5], ['C',1,3,1.66666666667], ['D',2,5,6]]
```

I'm new in python and try a lot e.g. this but it didn't work:

```
mylist2 = []
for item in mylist:
    if item[0] == list(mydict.keys()):
        mylist2 = mylist[0][1:] / list(mydict.keys())
print(mylist2)
```

Comment: You need a second loop over the list elements and divide each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension, using `key, *rest` to unpack the elements of `mylist` and using `dict.get` to get the divisor or 1 as default:

```
>>> [[key] + [x/mydict.get(key, 1) for x in rest] for key, *rest in mylist]
[['A', 2.0, 1.0, 2.5],
 ['C', 1.0, 3.0, 1.6666666666666667],
 ['D', 2.0, 5.0, 6.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

A single char (`item[0]`) can not be equal to a list of all `dict.keys()` which would be `['A','B','C']`:

> ```
> if item[0] == list(mydict.keys()):
> ```

You need to check if the `item[0]` is `in` the dict:

```
mylist = [['A',4,2,5], ['C',3,9,5], ['D',2,5,6]] 

mydict = {'A' : 2, 'B' : 6, 'C' : 3}

mylist2 = []
for item in mylist:
    key, *vals = item   # split into key and rest of list
    if key in mydict:
        mylist2.append([key])  # create new list, append it, fill it with key
        for val in vals:
            mylist2[-1].append(val/mydict[key])  # add the other numbers to last inner list
    else:
        mylist2.append(item[:])  # add a copy of item
print(mylist2)
```

Output:

```
[['A', 2.0, 1.0, 2.5], ['C', 1.0, 3.0, 1.6666666666666667], ['D', 2, 5, 6]]
```

---

This is the "long" version - you can reduce this using `dict.get(key,1)` wich returns the value of the key or 1 by default and a list comp to make it "slicker" - see Tobias_k [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53707069/7505395)

Answer (score 0):

Something like (quick and dirty, probably a more elegant solution but hopefully it helps you):

```
mydict = {'A' : 2, 'B' : 6, 'C' : 3}
mylist = [['A',4,2,5], ['C',3,9,5], ['D',2,5,6]]

for k,v in mydict.items():
    for j in mylist:
        if k == j[0]:
            j[1] = j[1] / v
            j[2] = j[2] / v
            j[3] = j[3] / v

print(mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hii B.T**
  i've Used a list Comprehension for your requirement,if you want try this:

```
  mydict = {'A' : 2, 'B' : 6, 'C' : 3}
  mylist = [['A',4,2,5], ['C',3,9,5], ['D',2,5,6]]

  print map(lambda x:map(lambda y:float(y/mydict.get(x[0],1)) if not isinstance(y,str) else y,x),mylist) 

  Result:[['A', 2.0, 1.0, 2.0], ['C', 1.0, 3.0, 1.0], ['D', 2.0, 5.0, 6.0]]
```

i hope you dont need explanation for this,map function just maps with each element in a list

Comment: this is python 2 - not python3 as asked. `map` returns no list in python3 and print is a function.

Comment: @PatrickArtner oops! i didn't see that,Ok anyways answer already Got by mehrdad-pedramfar ;) .Good remind!